# Image Effect on Hover not transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

Is it somehow possible to make a image have an hover effect if the hovered place of the image, is not transparent.

As I have a image with some transparent.

Then I want to make a hover effect which will first run when the mouse is over the image on a place where the image is not transparent.

Is that possible somehow?

Hope it is understand able.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is possible, somehow you can fix the position or coordinate value, I think you should use canvas and place your image inside it and with help of mouse event you can catch the mouse function and try to use jQuery for hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the map tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

Its possible using the canvas element and I actually made a plugin for this^^ Maybe this might help you: https://github.com/Bahlor/jQuery-Pixel-Related-Object-Selection

This script allows to check for transparent / non-transparent areas of an image and also allows clickthrough if another element is behind a transparent area of an overlapping element. Works with image elements and divs using background-image.